# Replace values falling within a range in a 2D array in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to replace all values smaller than -999 with NaN and values falling within -999 to 0 with -0.1 in a 2D array.

I can replace one value using

```
data[data < -999] = 'nan'
```

However, when I use

```
data[data < -999] = 'nan'
data[data < 0] = -0.1
```

It says

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
>     data[data < 0] = -0.1

How to replace values < -999 with `NaN` and values within the range of -999 to 0 with -0.1

Comment: Just to be clear, what data type is `data`?  What does `print(type(data))` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
data[data < -999] = 'nan'
```

Isn't doing what you think. `data < -999` evaluates to falsey in Python2.7, even though it's a weird thing to do; you're comparing a list to an int. This means the expression maps to

```
data[0] = 'nan'
```

Which is why you see only one value change. Note that this syntax is not allowed in Python3

It looks like you're trying to do

```
for column in data:
    for ix, num in enumerate(column):
        if num < -999:
            column[ix] = 'nan'
        elif num < 0:
            column[ix] = -0.1
```

A quick example of why yours doesn't work:

```
>>> data = [[-9999, -9999], [-9999, -9999]]
>>> data[data<-999] = 'nan'
>>> data
['nan', [-9999, -9999]]
>>>
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and has to replace the values in a 2D array. `data[data < -999] = 'nan'` worked fine for me. I was wondering whether I can use it further.

Comment: @Mario The only way it will appear to work will be if the only value in data less than `-999` is the very first. See my example above for a counterexample to it working

Comment: Yes, the first value in the 2D array was -9999, but it replaced all the those values with `NaN`, here the if else with for loop is not working for me.

Comment: @Mario apologies, I had a small typo; please try again

Comment: @Mario it's fixed to work for a two-dimensional array - let me know if you have an issue

Comment: Thanks @HumphreyTriscuit, it worked. Could you write few comments in your code to explain what each line exactly does.